Infinite coproduct in a category of groups
Let $\mathbf{Grp}$ be a category of groups.
Then, we know that there exists a coproduct $\bigsqcup_{I\in I} G_i$ for a family of  groups $\{G_i\}_{I\in I}$ in  $\mathbf{Grp}$ when $I$ is a finite set.
This coproduct is given by a free product $G_1*\cdots * G_n$ if $I=\{1,\dots,n\}$.
Now, I want to know how is this when $I$ is an infinite set.
In other words,

Is there a coprduct of $\{G_i\}_{i\in I}$ in  $\mathbf{Grp}$ for any cardinality set $I$ ?


In addition, if there exists, how is the coproduct constructed?

Please give me explanations or references, thank you.

Yes, it's the free product. It's constructed in exactly the same way as the free product with finitely many factors.

Thanks. But how? I can't image the generalization of finite free product to infinite free product. If you know, please give me appropriate reference.

Alternatively, it is the direct limit of the coproducts over the finite subsets of $I$ over the poset finite subsets.

What do you mean, "how"? Identically. The elements of the free product only involve finitely many factors, so what could possibly be the problem?

You are certainly right. I have a misunderstanding. Thanks.
